# Java - txt file not able to be located

Tags: java, file, directory

I am very new to programming, my only experience this far is doing class assignments, but I want to learn how to write and read from files so I can store data.

This code is very simple and should just be printing out the contents of two txt files named "stringList" and "intlist". However, when running the code, I receive these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

When experimenting earlier, I was able to make everything work fine and the txt files were reachable to the program, but for some reason it stopped working.

Here is the main method code:

```
import java.io.File; // Importing file class
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; // Importing ___ to throw exception from file directory 
import java.util.*; // Importing java utilities

 public class Main{ // Class header
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException { // Method header

        File stringList = new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\eclipse-workspace\\LearningFiles\\stringList.txt"); // Creating new File object "stringList" with stringList.txt as directory
        File intList = new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\eclipse-workspace\\LearningFiles\\intList.txt"); // Creating new File object "intList" with intList.txt as directory

        Scanner s = new Scanner(stringList); // Scanner reads stringList file
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(intList); // Scanner reads intList file

        System.out.println(s.next()); // Printing first word
        System.out.println(s.next()); // Printing second word
        System.out.println(s.next()); // Printing third word
        System.out.println(s.nextLine());
        System.out.println(s.nextLine()); // Printing entire second line

        int num1 = s1.nextInt(); // Saving first number as integer variable
        int num2 = s1.nextInt(); // Saving second number as integer variable

        System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + (num1+num2)); // Printing out result of integers added

    } // End of public void main
 } // End of main method
```

I've looked over many solutions in other threads but were unable to find any solutions that worked for me. I will list the solutions I have attempted:

1. txt files are not named "intList.txt", so the total file is **not** "intList.txt.txt".
2. Creating the txt files within the project folder itself.
3. The txt documents are on the same plane as the scr, not in a subfolder.
4. Including the direct folder path directory.

Help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Hi, can you add also the content of input files?

Comment: Yes, please provide the contents of your input file. I hope they are not empty ! Because if it is then scanner has nothing to read and will result in NoSuchElementException

Comment: @Shubham Oh gosh, in creating new files I forgot to add my data back, working just fine now. Thank you!

Comment: @A.Wolf , Forgot to add my data back after deleting and re-creating my files a couple times, working just fine now! Thank you! ^-^

Comment: why don't you delete this question.  It is of no use to anyone